# VS Code is unable to locate python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been looking at similar problems and everyone has a promising solution which usually revolves around changing the interpreter path.  I have done my best but have run out of solutions that I can think of.  I'm hoping someone else knows how and thank you for any comments.[image: No version of python ever appear, I have tried to enter the path in the box at the top but have had no luck]

No version of python ever appears, I have tried to enter the path in the box at the top but have had no luck

[image]

I want to switch from 3.10 to 3.9 and this is when not being able to select the version of python became a problem.  The picture above is from the terminal within VS Code

[image]

This is the default path I have entered in VS Code

[image]
The photo above is from the Windows command prompt, locating the active version of python

[image]

I would like to be able to use Python 3.10 in some folders and 3.9 in others, however at the moment I really just need VS Code to see 3.9, I imagine once I know what has gone wrong at this stage it will be smooth sailing from here.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled pretty much anything I can think could be related

I really hope I have just made a stupid mistake somewhere and it is really obvious, thank you again

Comment: Your vscode is correctly displaying the only python version installed on your system which is python 3.10. Try googling 'pyenv'. It's a tool to manage multiple versions of python which I think fits your goals. You should use it to install 3.9, then accordingly 3.9 would be available as a choice.

Comment: @fridge from the time of this post to now, I uninstalled both of my versions of python and installed only 3.9, which has been detected properly but cannot be detected by VS Code.  I will look into pyenv but surely VScode should be able to access python when given the exact path?

Comment: Should be,.Use the 'enter interpreter path' option to locate 3.9's interpreter.

Comment: @fridge Thank you for your help, unfortunately, what you suggested was not the solution.  However, I am currently looking into the environments as I think it may be beneficial.  I fixed the issue by installing a previous version of the python extension, and immediately all version were available :)